# Truncate a number in mathematica

Tags: precision-and-accuracy, machine-precision, arbitrary-precision

I want to truncate a simple number to n decimal digits. For example, 2/3. I used

`f[x_, n_] := N[IntegerPart[x 10^n]/10^n]`

but I get

`f[2/3, 20] = 0.666667`

Is there a way to get

`f[2/3, 20] = 0.66666666666666666666` ?

I have searched a lot but I haven't really found an answer. I am looking for something like `N` or `Round` for truncation.

Comment: just try `N[2/3, 20]`

Comment: `N` rounds the last decimal digit. I get `N[2/3, 20] = 0.66666666666666666667`

Comment: You probably want to use `RealDigits[2/3, 10, 20]`

Comment: `NumberForm[N[2/3], 30]` stops after 15 to 16 decimals but does not round up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f]
f[x_, n_] := 
Module[{s = RealDigits[x, 10, n + IntegerLength@IntegerPart[x]]}, 
N[FromDigits[s[[1]]]/10^(n), n + s[[2]]]];

f[2/3, 20]
```

> 0.66666666666666666666

Answer (score 2):

`Trunc[x_, n_] := N[FromDigits[RealDigits[x, 10, n]], n]` also works.

Comment: Nice, I made a change in my code so that you always get `n` decimal digits like  f[5000/3, 20]=1666.66666666666666666666. thanx for accepting